# How Can I Format My Internal Storage?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I Have A UBISLATE 7C+ (EDGE). One Day, I Formatted Its Internal Storage With My PC. But I Saw None Of The Files Were Deleted From The Internal Storage. From That Day Onwards, Its Internal Storage's Data Is Not Getting Erased And I Am Also Unable To Save Any File Into It. PLEASE, Suggest Me Some Ways To Make It Normal! Is There Any Way ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are rooted and have a custom recovery, then you can format data from there